# Atom, invisibles => new line character

Tags: html, powerpoint, atom-editor

Atom is ignoring this character:  (in PowerPoint it is a new line character).
"Show invisibles" do not help me in this case. 
Any ideas to solve it? Thank you.

Comment: show invisibles shows carriage returns http://i.imgur.com/ewg42ru.png

Comment: Seems like it is still missing function in Atom.io and the team is aware of it. https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/12157